# Difficulty loading pecl stats module w/ php 5.6 fpm

Tags: php, nginx, pecl

Experiencing difficulty getting PECL stats module loaded in Vagrant dev environment.
**Dev Env: Ubuntu 14.04, Nginx 1.4.6, PHP 5.6.24.**

Production copy running successfully.
**Prod Env: Ubuntu 14.04, Nginx 1.4.6, PHP 5.5.9.**

We need to migrate the application to a new server.  New server node is the same env setup as the Dev/Vagrant box listed above. Only environment change between current node & new node is PHP version.

PHP5.6-FPM service is running as expected in Vagrant.  The application works as expected, until attempting to run any php stats methods, for example stats_standard_deviation().

PECL stats 1.0.5 has been installed & verified.
[image: pecl list]

Confirmed the correct php.ini via phpinfo() prior to adding stats extension.

[image: location of php.ini]

[image: php extension dir]

[image: stats.so extension in php.ini]

Confirmed the stats.so extension exists.
[image: stats.so extension file confirmation]

I've restarted services, restarted the Vagrant box.  I've confirmed stats module is loaded in production via phpinfo() & am using the same method to confirm it is NOT loading in dev.  Just can't seem the get the extension loaded.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

This was a two-part issue.

1. An incorrect PECL dependency was installed. `php5-dev` was the pkg installed, which directed the PECL installer to use `PHP API 20121212`
2. PECL config looks for standard PHP 5 install by default, v. 5.5.9.  That needed to reflect the correct settings.  Possibly using either `pkg-config` or `autoconfig` packages would rectify this hiccup by assisting PECL in the PHP detection process.

**Solution**

Clean out the PECL stats module, as well as the php dev package.
Set PECL config.
Then re-install correct versions.

```
# Clean out previous ver.
$ pecl uninstall stats-1.0.5  
$ apt-get remove --purge php5-dev  

# Install correct PECL dependency
$ apt-get install php5.6-dev  

# Set PECL config to correct PHP install
$ pecl config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php5.6  
$ pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/5.6/fpm

# Re-install PECL package & restart PHP-FPM service
$ pecl install stats-1.0.5  
$ service php5.6-fpm restart
```